# How to create a singleton of a custom class and inject it other classes in .Net core 2.0? 'No service for type 'Services' has been registered.'?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a class in a .Net core 2.0 console application. The class provides data service and will be used by the Main class. So a singleton of the class will be created for DI.

```
public class Services
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public Services(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Items> GetList(string region)
    {
        return _context.Items;
    }
}
```

The following code is in `Program` class.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<Main>(); // With constructor of public Main(Services service)
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
....
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(defaultConn));
services.AddSingleton<Services>();
var s = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Services>(); // Error
services.AddSingleton(s);
```

However, the second to the last line got the error of

> 'No service for type 'Services' has been registered.'

?

The `Main` class will need to access a singleton of `Services` using DI.

Comment: You're not registering the `DbContext` with the `ServiceCollection`.

Comment: I did. The line was omitted. Just added.

Comment: Where does your service provider come from?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, it's a .Net core 2.0 app. I used the built-in providers.

Comment: I mean that if you didn't build it from the service collection with which you registered the desired service, how can the provider provide it

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I've updated the question with the line to build service provider. I also moved the line `services.AddSingleton<Services>();` after `DbContext` and the error message is different now.

Comment: Thanks. Given that, why are you doing this in the first place? Why 1) register a singleton service with a container, 2) build a provider from that container, 3) retrieve the service registered from that provider, 4) register that very service as a singleton in the container that it originally came from?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, Basically I just want to assign `Services _services` in class `Main` by injecting a singleton of `Service`. Is there a better way to have it done? Maybe I shouldn't use DI?

Comment: @ca9163d9 once the provider is built. it will not have knowledge of any additional services added to the service collection.

Comment: Please be aware that your `DbContext` is a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) because of its `Singleton` consumer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the service provider is built, it will not have knowledge of any additional services added to the service collection. Only build the provider once all the types have been added.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<Main>(); // With constructor of public Main(Services service)

//....
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(defaultConn));
services.AddSingleton<Services>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var s = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Services>(); // Should work now
```

When `Main` is resolved the singleton will be injected

```
var main = serviceProvider.GetService<Main>(); //will include singleton Service
```